# Javafx ListView gets equals(null) called when clicking for the first time on an item

Tags: java, listview, javafx, null

I have this very simple class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    @FXML
    private ListView<CustomObj> listView;

    class CustomObj {
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            System.out.println("equals " + obj);

            if (obj != null) {
                if (super.equals(obj))
                    return true;
                if (obj.getClass() == getClass())
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("layout.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        ObservableList<CustomObj> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        list.addAll(new CustomObj(), new CustomObj());
        listView.setItems(list);
    }

    @FXML
    void itemClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("clicked " + listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And this is the used FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="337.0" prefWidth="314.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="a.b.c.App">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="69.0" onMouseClicked="#itemClicked" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The weird behaviour happens when I click on an item in the ListView, it looks like item.equals(null) is called, I'm not sure why it calls equals() but fact is that the parameter passed is null, at least this happens only the first time I click on an item. It doesn't happen if I use a ListView of String instead than CustomObj. Any idea of why and of who calls equals() when I click?

Comment: I might not be right, but I would say that the `ListView` is trying to see if the newly selected item is equals to the old item (which is `null` because is selected). Anyways, how did you know it doesn't happen for `String`? `String` is final and there is no way you can tell it gets called and if it gets called what parameter is passed in.

Comment: When I use ListView<String> instead of ListView<CustomObj> equals() doesn't get called at all. Anyway I think you're right about why equals() is called, so this means null has to be checked in equal() from within a custom object, so if I ever would like not to check it(I'm not sure why I shouldn't) then it would throw me a NullPointerException if I try accessing obj properties from within equals().

Comment: Actually, I think `equals()` is being called even if it is `String`. There is no way you would have known `equals()` is being called unless you know where it is being called from, and that you have placed a breakpoint there. But if you have managed to do that, then you would have understood why it has been called.

Comment: You're right. And I see String does the class check this way "if (anObject instanceof String)" instead of the way I used in my CustomObj "if (obj.getClass() != getClass())", in the String way no exceptions will be trown if the object to compare is null.

Comment: @Jai "There is no way you would have known equals() is being called unless.." you could also override `equals()` and printout a simple message

Comment: @c0der `String` is a `final` class.